# Having trouble to loop through dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm learning Python and I'm having some trouble to loop through dictionaries. I want to loop through the whole dictionary and print every value with this code:

```
d = {"Room" : 100, "Day" : 25, "Night" : 88}

for key in d:
    print d[key]
```

But get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I don't suppose you think that that error message might be significant in any way? In which case, maybe you should tell us what it is.

Comment: Better, but which line is line 9?

Comment: The `d` in the question is not your actual `d`, is it?

Comment: What do you mean my actual `d`?

Comment: Try deleting your code and copy/pasting it from your question. Your snippet works for me (see my initial answer). You seemed to have snuck an odd character in the last line.

Comment: You're right I don't know what character I wrote before

Comment: Perhaps "Á", that's `0xc3` in Latin-1 aka https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1. Your Problem has nothing to do with the dictionary, but with encoding.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have a look that the Python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) documentation. If you want to iterate over values:

```
for value in d.values():
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You snuck invalid characters in your code. Python2 uses ascii encoding by default, so it doesn't tolerate characters over 127 (which 0xc3 == 195 is). Since it seems like a mistake, delete the whole problematic line and retype it — your snippet worked just fine here.

You could also set the encoding to utf-8, which should remove the error. However you should avoid this fix, as it does not seem appropriate for this occasion:

```
# top of the file
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

---

intial answer, before actual error:

You're using Python version 3+, which has changed semantics for `print`. It's a function now, so do as the error suggests and use `print(somevalue)`.

Python2:

```
>>> for key in d:
...     print d[key]
... 
88
100
25
>>> type(print)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(print)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python3:

```
>>> for key in d:
...     print d[key]
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print d[key]
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Comment: Huh. so you downvoted everyone else's answer, when yours is plainly wrong. How do you know he's using [tag:python3.x]?

Comment: I downvoted all the other answers. None of them address what's wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: Why would I do that? Anyway, added some reasoning.

Answer (score -1):

Simply saying, here is what sublime asked me when I run your code:
Did you mean print(d[key]) ?  :-)

You can also use:

```
d = {"Room" : 100, "Day" : 25, "Night" : 88}
for key in d:
    v = d[key]
    print(v)
```

Explanation in case needed:
for each element in 'd' dictionary:
create variable called 'v' assigned to each element in d /
print variable v

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -3):

you can use:

```
d = {"Room" : 100, "Day" : 25, "Night" : 88}

for key, value in d.items():
     print key, value
```